# Is there a way to display the date of the scheduled event on the calendar immediately following adding a date to the calendar?

Tags: ios, applications, calendar

Maybe I was spoiled by using the calendar app on PalmOS, but on iOS when you add an event to the calendar it does not display the date that event was scheduled on immediately and automatically after typing in the event.  This means that if you enter an event in haste you get no warning if you have double booked something; you have to manually find that date and time to check if you have double booked.

Is there any way to display the date and time of the event in the context of that day after entering an event?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. You have to manually find the event in context to check for any double-bookings.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html